# sbt dist works in terminal but not with Jenkins as shell script

Tags: shell, jenkins, sbt, jenkins-pipeline

I am completely new to both sbt and Jenkins. I am trying to construct a build plan using Jenkins piplelines. The following commands run just fine within shell script: `sbt compile` & `sbt package`

However, `sbt dist` does not work. I get the error `not a valid command`

What is puzzling me, I can run the command from terminal just fine.
[image]

For what its workth, here is the contents of jenkinsfile (I know `sbt dist` should be in build, but I am still experimenting):

```
pipeline {
  agent any
  stages {
    stage('Build') {
      parallel {
        stage('Build') {
          steps {
            sh 'echo "Compiling... "'
            sh 'sbt compile'
          }
        }
        stage('Deploy') {
          steps {
            sh 'echo "Deploying... "'
            sh 'echo "packaging.. "'
            sh 'sbt dist'
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Jenkins 2.89.1, sbt tried both: 0.13 and 1.0.x

Comment: there is no `dist` task in bare-bone SBT. So it just tells you it can't find such a task. Probably you meant to use some SBT plugin which defines the `dist` task? There is a `publish` task in the SBT, probably you are looking for it.

Comment: @AlexanderArendar does this mean `dist` is installed on the machine but not used by `jenkins`? is there any sbt task does the same as `dist` (produce zip file)?

Comment: To my knowledge there is nothing called `dist` in SBT. Would be helpful to know why exactly you decided that there should be a `dist` task there. `package` task produces a .jar file. Try look at https://github.com/sbt/sbt-native-packager SBT plugin, it can be used to build .zip and much more.

Comment: @AlexanderArendar When I run `sbt dist` first time, it loads some libraries/plugin and then it works from terminal. The problem I am facing, it does not work from Jenkins whithin shell script. Perhaps because that plugin is not added to jenkins. The same goes to `native-packager`. My goal is to produce zip file from jenkins. Hence, I probabaly need a jenkins compatible plugin that produces zip. Thanks for your input

Comment: @AlexanderArendar and here is where got the `dist` from : https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.6.x/Deploying

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see now from comments that you are working on Play application, so it is clear now where the `dist` task comes from.

In Jenkins first thing that you need to make when you running SBT tasks is that you have loaded to SBT your `build.xml` of your project. In your shell script it is not actually visible whether you are in the root project folder or not.

Also Jenkins has integration with SBT better then just running it through shell script. You need to add [this plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/sbt+plugin) to Jenkins first. Look at the attached screenshot, where part of one of my Jenkins projects is shown:
[image]

There is a special kind of build step in Jenkins. In your project configuration you should see it under the "Build step" dropdown:
[image]

I believe you should start from there. If you still need to run through shell script make sure you also `cd /path/to/your/project` folder before running SBT commands.

Comment: `you have loaded to SBT your build.xml of your project` Could you explain more? What is `build.xml` file? and where can I find it?

Comment: I think you need to read more about building projects with SBT before doing some work with it. Start with SBT documentation, it has quite good getting started section:http://www.scala-sbt.org/1.x/docs/Getting-Started.html

Answer (score 0):

I accepted @Alexander Arendar answer, as it is the correct answer. I just want to elaborate on how I got it right, so it can be useful for others.

The answer as @Alexander mentioned is `If you still need to run through shell script make sure you also cd /path/to/your/project folder before running SBT commands`. I was actually doing that. But what I was completely oblivious to, is that `cd` to directory and running `sbt dist` must be withiin the same jenkins step. I was doing that in two separate steps, and ending up running `sbt dist` in the original directory.

One worthy note is, cd to project was needed only for `sbt dist` since it comes with `Play`. Standard sbt commands (e.g.: sbt compile) were running fine outside the play project directory.